# Search for 'Poland' does not find a Krakow job

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search, geography

This job ad (in Krakow): http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/17319/net-developer-r-d-team-working-on-next-medius-poland?a=ksEJROU

Does not show up in this search (location=Poland): http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=Poland&range=20

Kraków is actually in Poland, so I believe it *should* show up in the above search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was some cached data in there, it should be better now. Would you try it again?